# How do I change this Windows Form code to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I wrote a code in Windows form with a **checkbox** that enable an **Update** button when the user check. Now, I am required to change the code into WPF because of UI requirement. How can I convert this code below into a working format in WPF.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    License_agreement();
}
private void License_agreement()
{
    updatebutton.Enabled = checkBoxforupdate.Checked;
}
```

My attempted codes is below:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    checkboxlincense.IsChecked = true;
}

private void License_agreement()
{
    updatebutton.Enabled = checkboxlincense.Checked;
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to do it. I just needed to Disable the Update button initially in the property section such as: IsEnabled="False"..

Comment: You need to remove the static binding code from codebehind, and use the mode property of control. Please understand why we use WPF, when already had Window Forms?

Answer (score 2):

I would do it in the XAML rather than the code behind.

Set the Button's `IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=checkboxlincense, Path=IsChecked}"`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    checkboxlincense.IsChecked = true;
}
```

...to:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    checkboxlincense.IsChecked = true;
    License_agreement();
}

private void License_agreement()
{
    updatebutton.Enabled = checkboxlincense.IsChecked;
}
```

I will leave it to you to simplify but this closest matches your original code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. I just needed to Disable the Update button initially in the property section such as: IsEnabled="False".

Comment: And if you untick the box, does it disable the button?

Comment: The posted code doesn't call `license_agreement`, so how does `updateButton.Enabled` get changed?